# In Java: How to rollback when update Active Directory or database fail?

Tags: java, active-directory, commit, rollback, transactionscope

In Java, I have 2 methods to do:

1. Update some attribute data in the AD.
2. Update some data in the field in the table.

   - If item 1 or Item 2 fail system must be rollback.
   - I want to do which if both items updated complete then commit the process.
   - If one of them were failed, transaction must be rollbacked.

I found in the .NET TransactionScope but in the Java I don't know.

Does anyone help/advise me how to do it in this solution?

Answer (score 0):

if you use entreprise java bean (ejb).
the container manages your transactions and make them as one unit of work , if one of them Fails all other will be rolled back.
if you dont use ejb,
you have to use a persistent provider like hibernate.
and wrap your methods call with try catch block,
in catch block call rollback method.

```
  try{Session ss = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = ss.getTransaction();method 1();method 2();tx.commit();}  catch(Exception e){tx.rollback();}finally{ss.close();}
```

Comment: As I know Hibernate support only RDBMS but some my method are access Active Directory (Not RDBMS) so that how should I do?

Comment: to rollback database update you can  use hibernate or other persistence provider. In the catch block do what can cancel your method1.